In jupyter notebook, how to use venv to manage package?
I am starting to use venv to manage my packages.
Here I could use terminal to do it, but I want to do it in jupyter notebook, so that I could do the installation during my software dev work smoothly.
However, when I created and activated my virtual env, it seems jupyter didn't confirm me in the virtual env.
First I run this two command to create and activate the venv
!python -m venv first_venv
!source first_venv/bin/activate

Then when I run pip install faker it was still installed in the system folder like /usr/local/lib/... rather than under virtual env lib folder first_venv/lib/pythonx.x/... (please uninstall it by pip uninstall faker,else you may not see what I described below)
If I want to install it in virtual env, I have to run: !first_venv/bin/pip install faker which is ugly and tedious, furthermore, I can't import the faker module I installed this ugly way.
So actually I am not in the "virtual env mode", I am still in the normal env mode in my jupyter notebook.
So,is there a way to activate my virtual env then do everything in my virtual env in jupyter notebook? Or if I can't, I could only use terminal to do this, please let me know, too.
In short, how could I smoothly using pip to install and uninstall packages in virtual env and I could import directly and firstly from my virtual env; if it is not in virtual env, I don't want to import it from system library, I want all package I used self-contained in virtual env.

My answer does not directly help you fixing your problem, but it's a workaround I usually do:
What I normally do is:

create a venv (python3 -m venv venv_name)
activate it (unix-like: source venv_name/bin/activate)
install jupyter notebook in that venv while it's activated (pip install notebook)
open the jupyter notebook (jupyter notebook)

This way your jupyter is executed with the interpreter inside your venv and everything works corretly. It can be confirmed by checking the address of:
import sys
print(sys.executable)

Then you could also install packages using !pip install... and it will be placed inside the venv's environment. !pip list also shows that.
The downside is that instead of somehow telling the jupyter to use that environment, we're install a jupyter notebook inside the venv which may or may not be what you want. It comes with other packages as dependencies too. If it's not a problem then use it.

Thanks for the very quick answer, may be the quickest I have met; I will try your solution and give you feedback, the situation is I am using jupyterhub in my company's server; so I don't know if start a new jupyter notebook in virtual env is a workable solution.
